# Multivariable Chain Rule. Where is my mistake?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, function-and-relation-composition, chain-rule

Say $x=\sqrt{z^2+y^2}$.

For a function $f(y,z)$, we have

$$
\tag{1}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \ .
$$

By definition of $x$, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 - z^2}} = \frac{x}{y} \ , \tag{2}\\ 
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 - y^2}} = \frac{x}{z} \ .\tag{3}\\ 
\end{align}
Therefore 
$$
\tag{4}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{x}{y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{x}{z} \ .
$$

---

Now assume $f(y,z) = e^{\sqrt{y^2 + z^2}}$. We have

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = e^{\sqrt{y^2 + z^2}} \frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2 + z^2}}  = e^x\frac{y}{x}\ , \tag{5}\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = e^{\sqrt{y^2 + z^2}} \frac{z}{\sqrt{y^2 + z^2}} = e^x\frac{z}{x}\ . \tag{6}\\
\end{align}
By $(4)$, we have
$$
\tag{7}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = e^x\frac{y}{x}\frac{x}{y} + e^x\frac{x}{z}\frac{z}{x} = 2e^x\ . 
$$
But that can't be right, because $f = e^x$, so it must be 
$$
\tag{8}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = e^x \neq 2e^x \ . 
$$

---

So where is my mistake?

Comment: Tangential comment, but notice that in equation (1) the letter $f$ is being used to denote two different functions.  The function $f$ on the left is not the same function as the $f$ on the right.  This is a common abuse of notation, but I think it causes some confusion.

Comment: Also, in Equation (3), you mean $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ on the LHS.

Comment: f is sometimes x so make no sense

Comment: @rogerl: yes, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've written really doesn't make sense. You start with a function $f(u)=e^u$ — a function of a single variable. Then you have $u=g(y,z)$. So, letting $F(y,z) = f(g(y,z))$, we have
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = f'(g(y,z))\frac{\partial g}{\partial y},$$
and similarly for the $z$ partial.

With $f(u) = e^{\sqrt u}$, this gives
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \frac1{2\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}e^{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}\cdot 
2y = \frac y{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}e^{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}.$$

Comment: What is $u$ in your example?

Comment: $u=y^2+z^2$. I could have done it with $e^u$ and $u=\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$. Do it both ways.

Comment: I think your comment addresses equations $(5)$ and $(6)$, but I see we get the same. I'd like to understand where I'm making a mistake in equation $(7)$ with $df/dx$ when you consider $y(x)$ and $z(x)$ functions of $x$.

Comment: $\partial f/\partial x$ just makes no sense at all. You've turned everything upside down. What you mean by $\partial f/\partial x$ should be my $f'(x)$. You need to parse the function correctly to start with. To be explicit, a general function $f(y,z)$ won't be a function of $x$ at all, so what you're writing can't make sense.

Comment: Okay maybe I need to take a step back. Say I start with a function $f(x)$ and then I say $x=g(y,z)$. What's the way to relate $f'(x)$ with an expression involving $\partial F/\partial y$ and $\partial F/\partial z$, where $F(y,z) = f(g(y,z))$.

Comment: That's precisely what my answer indicates.

Comment: What I mean is: is there a correct way to write an equation $f'(x) = {...}$ where the RHS involves $\partial F/\partial y$ and $\partial F/\partial z$

Comment: Seriously? Sit and work through my answer. And then work through it again! That's precisely what it is, but, no, you won't have $f'(x)$ on one side by itself unless you do algebra.